# why does writing to file and printing to console look different

Tags: java, encryption

I have programmed a program that encrypts and decrypts a file using the SDES algorithm, now for testing purposes a was printing to the console. Everything works, when the program runs the user is asked to enter some text and then enter a key after that the program does its magic and the text gets encrypted. The problem is when i write that same text to a file it looks different from the one on the console. Here's what its looks like in the console when you encrypt the following sentence "hi how are you"[how text looks after being encrypted in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsOtR.png)

And heres how it looks when written to file {?dW?'??d}  they clearly dont look the same and i need them to look the same for decryption purposes.
here's the code i used for writing to file.

```
public class writeFile
{
public void write(String write)
{
  try(Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("yoyo.txt"),"ASCII")))



 {
      writer.write(write);
    }
catch(IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println("incorect file path");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Probably an encoding/charset issue.

Comment: Try using the `UTF-8` or `UTF-16` encoding.

Comment: There are a lot of `?` because the `ASCII` encoding doesn't support all the characters of your string.

Comment: Encryption produces arbitrary byte patterns that don't correspond to any valid character set, so using UTF-8 or UTF-16 won't work. The most reasonable way to view ciphertext is to use a hex display utility, like `hexdump` in Linux. There are many hex dump utilities for windows also.

Comment: Seems to work when i use UTF-16 but when i use this, Scanner which i am using to read the file doesn't or is unable to read the file anymore. But when i switch back to ascii it seems to work. Any thoughts on this.

Comment: @JamesKPolk That's it. Post it as an answer?